# If a univariate function has directional derivatives on the whole domain, does this imply that it is differentiable except on a countable set?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose we have a univariate function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  It is well-known that if both directional derivatives of the function exist at a point then the function is differentiable at that point.  Of course, even if both directional derivatives exist, it is possible that they are different values at a point, in which case the function is not differentiable at that point.

**My Question:** If both directional derivatives exist over the whole domain (i.e., all real numbers), does this imply that $f$ is *differentiable except on a countable set* (i.e., that the directional derivatives match except on a countable set)?  Intuitively that seems right to me, but I'm not sure how to prove it.